# A question about generalized Dyck words

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am interested in counting the following.  How many words using $n-1$ copies of $u$ and ${n \choose 2} - n+1$ copies of $d$ begin with $uu$ and, in general, the $k^{th}$ $u$ is among the first ${k \choose 2} + 1$ letters in the word?

This is a generalization of a Dyck path.  I need to start at the origin, end at $(n-1,2(n-1)-{n \choose 2})$, and always stay above the corresponding curve.

I'm looking for a reference or an argument that gives a formula analogous to the Catalan numbers.  I can write down the answer as a messy sum.

Thanks!

Comment: It would just be more fun to read this question if you were giving some background on why you consider such paths.

Answer (score 3):

*(After the original question was edited).*
Now this is simply http://oeis.org/A107877. Your words are in one-to-one correspondence to those mentioned in a comment by David Scambler. To come from your words to his, you need to add $d$ after each $u$, and then to replace $k$th $u$ by $k$ consecutive $u$'s.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!  I noticed a slight mistake in my question.  I meant that I want $n-1$ copies of $u$.  But this doesn't seem to change your solution much, as now I simply know that the final string of letters must be $d$s.

Thanks again!